# R string split and compress empty space

Tags: r, string, space

This is supposed to be as simple question but I couldn't figure it out. I'm trying to use a given variables list to choose data variables, however, apply string split I got 8 instead of 5. Clearly, the extra spaces were splited into empty variables for 1,3,5.  Any hints on  how to solve this?

```
 list <- " ethnicity_source_value  race_source_value  gender_source_value dx_age site"
  unlist(strsplit(list, " "))
[1] ""                       "ethnicity_source_value" ""                      
[4] "race_source_value"      ""                       "gender_source_value"   
[7] "dx_age"                 "site"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string already had a leading space, so we use `trimws` to remove those leading/lagging spaces, and then use `strsplit` with `split` as one or more spaces (`\\s+`).  It is possible that there are more than a single spaces in between the words.

```
unlist(strsplit(trimws(list), "\\s+"))
[1] "ethnicity_source_value" "race_source_value"      "gender_source_value"    "dx_age"                
[5] "site"
```

---

Or another option is `scan` which removes the whitespace automatically

```
scan(text = list, what = "", quiet = TRUE)
[1] "ethnicity_source_value" "race_source_value"      "gender_source_value"    "dx_age"                
[5] "site"
```

Comment: Further than this answer above, any other tricks to make the same list become c("ethnicity_source_value","race_source_value ","gender_source_value", "dx_age","site")? I tried as.list(scan(text = list, what = "", quiet = TRUE),sep=',') but seems like it didn't return what is intended. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like dput only make it temporary. Once being assigned, it went back again. factd <- as.character(dput(fact))
c("Race", "Gender", "Ethnicity", "year_of_birth")
> factd
[1] "Race"          "Gender"        "Ethnicity"     "year_of_birth"

Answer (score 4):

We could also use `str_squish` from `stringr` package; `str_squish()` also reduces repeated whitespace inside a string:

```
library(stringr)
unlist(strsplit(str_squish(list), " "))
```

```
[1] "ethnicity_source_value" "race_source_value"     
[3] "gender_source_value"    "dx_age"                
[5] "site
```